# How to access parent Model DB props (_id of parent parent) inside children Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I am having Model Data Relationship in Rails
Ex, 4 Models. Account, Role and Grant Model which belongs_to Account and RoleGrant Model which belongs to both Role and Grant Model.
Now, i need to access account_id of Role and Grant Model INSIDE RoleGrant Model in order to compare their account_id.

I try really hard but can't resolve this even after hours of searching.
I know that i can access (in rails console for example) RoleGrant.last.role.account and will get account with account_id i need but how to do this inside RoleGrant Model in order to validate Role and Grant account_id are same?

Code below is showing RoleGrant class which is doing validation for :role and :grant Model only.

```
class RoleGrant < ApplicationRecord
  # Description
  # An RoleGrant specifies an Grant within role

  # Includes
  include DefaultPolicyInfo

  # Relations
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :grant

  # Belongs_to Validation
  validates :role_id,
            presence: { if: -> { !role_id.nil? && role_id_changed? }, message: :not_valid },
            numericality: { allow_nil: false, only_integer: true, message: :numericality_not_blank }

  validates :grant_id,
            presence: { if: -> { !grant_id.nil? && grant_id_changed? }, message: :not_valid },
            uniqueness: { scope: %i[role_id] },
            numericality: { allow_nil: false, only_integer: true, message: :numericality_not_blank }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do a validation around that would suggest adding a custom validation like for example

```
def validate_same_account_ids
  errors.add(:base, 'Role and Grant account_ids do not match!') if role.account_id != grant.account_id
end
```

Then you can call this before_validation so something like

```
before_validation :validate_same_account_ids
```

But you might want to add an extra check as well to see if you have actually role and grant present in the RoleGrant record that you are creating

Comment: Yep, but i can't access role or grant inside RoleGrant Model.
I can access RoleGrant.last.account and etc but can't do this what i need.
I see :grant  and :role are accessible as this model RoleGrant in DB have: role_id and grant_id, but i need their db prop account_id :)

Comment: if you try to debug do you have role_id and grant_id present in the object ?

Comment: Yep i solved this with checking if i actually have role_id and grant_id.
Thank you very much Rilind :)